# Generate a series of lists of increasing length of consecutive integers

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a positive integer `n`; print `n-1` lists, of increasing lengths and consisted of consecutive integers in Python.

Example: For `n=4`, it should print the lists (in order):

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4]], [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

I tried with various options from `itertools`, but no luck.

*EDIT* Here's one failed attepmt with `combinations`:

```
n = 4
from itertools import product, permutations, tee, combinations
for i in range(n):
    print list(combinations(range(1, n+1), r = i))
```

It prints

```
[()]
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]
```

The problem here is (except the blank list at first line), it prints more elements in 3rd and 4th line.

Comment: Perhaps you could post one of your attempts and the (wrong) output it gives and we can see where the problem in your thinking is.

Comment: @quamrana Just added one such attempt... Need to get rid of few of the entries in `itertools.combinations`...

Comment: FYI: `itertools.combinations` returns all possible combinations given the input. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) which makes this function easier to understand: `combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need loops and slicing:

```
def increasingLengths(n):
    ret = []
    sample = [i + 1 for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(1, n):
        aList = []
        maxItems = n - i + 1
        for j in range(maxItems):
            aList.append(sample[j:j + i])
        ret.append(aList)
    return ret

print(increasingLengths(4))
```

Output:

```
[[[1], [2], [3], [4]], [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**To offer an alternative solution:**

I would use an `overlapping` function. I think some people call it a `window` function (?).

Something like this:

```
from collections import deque

def overlapping(seq, n):
    result = deque(seq[:n], maxlen=n)
    yield tuple(result)
    for x in seq[n:]:
        result.append(x)
        yield tuple(result)
```

Which will give you:

```
>>> list(overlapping('abcdefg', 3))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('c', 'd', 'e'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('e', 'f', 'g')]
```

[Peter Norvig has a lovely implementation of this.](https://github.com/norvig/pytudes/blob/master/ipynb/Advent%202017.ipynb)

Using that it's fairly simple to do what you wanted:

```
def increasing_lengths(n):
    seq = list(range(1, n + 1))
    for i in range(1, n):
        yield list(overlapping(seq, i))

>>> list(increasing_lengths(4))
[[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)], [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]]
```

You could also do this without using `collections`, but it won't be as short.

There you go, my two cents.